# How to add JQuery code to drupal site

Tags: views, javascript, 7

I am trying to add my JQuery code to my drupal 7 site.

In my drupal based site i have image in the featured block.
My JQuery code slides up the image after 2 seconds.

When i added the JQuery code to my page it is showing the JQuery code on the page.

Here is my code:

```
<script src="/drupal/sites/default/files/js/jquery.min.js"></script><script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sec1").slideUp(7000);
});
</script>
```

when i save the configuration, below codes are displayed in web page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".sec1").slideUp(7000);
    });
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: See [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](https://drupal.org/node/756722).

Comment: @Mithun cj before asking a question, use search

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know how to add your js code to drupal, there are two ways:

1. Create js file in your `theme_folder/js`, e.g, scripts.js, put your code into that file, open .info file of theme and add `scripts[]=js/scripts.js`
2. Create a js file as I wrote above and open template.php of your theme and put

   ```
   drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'YOUR_THEME_NAME') . '/js/scripts.js', array('type' => 'file', 'group' => JS_THEME));
   ```

   in `YOUR_THEME_preprocess_page()`. 
   (This is not an ideal way, but it shows how you can use a drupal_add_js() function)

also read [documentation](https://drupal.org/node/756722) for more info.

Comment: Don't use `drupal_add_js`, _always_ use `['#attached']['js']` in a render array when that option is available

Comment: @Clive Thanks for the advice. ['#attached']['js'] is especially important with forms (I already faced such a problem), because of validation doesn't apply form's drupal_add_js (if it has been used in form generation function)..

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that thanks for the tip

Comment: Kirill Cebotari from ProPeople posted a great article a few days ago comparing [7 different ways you can add JS to Drupal](http://wearepropeople.com/blog/7-ways-to-add-custom-js-and-css-to-a-page-in-drupal).