# Adding Manual Code to Front Page

Tags: theming, blocks

I have written HTML code which includes some JQuery code and some CSS. It basically gives me the Advanced Search button (some select button, text box and submit button). I have tested it outside Drupal and it is working perfectly. I have written whole code in one file. When I tried to copy that code and put it in the blocks, it messed up the front page. I removed it. All the CSS, styling of Front page was messed up.

How do I add that code in Drupal so that it shows me that advanced search block on the content region of the Front Page?

[image: Output 1]

[image: Output 2]

I have attached the Output. I hope you will understand the code now.

**CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#less").hide();
  $("#more").click(function(){
   $(".views-widget_before").hide();
    $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
    $("#more").slideUp();
    $("#less").slideDown();
  });

 $("#less").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
    $(".views-widget_before").show();
    $("#less").slideUp();
   $("#more").slideDown();

  });
});

</script>

<style type="text/css"> 
#panel,#flip
{

//padding:15px;
//text-align:center;
//background-color:#e5eecc;
//border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#panel
{
//padding:50px;
display:none;
}
</style>

<style>

.views-widget
{
display:inline;
float:left;
padding: 0.5em 1em 0 0;
}
div
{
margin:0;
border:0;
outline:0;
font-size: 100%;
vertical-align: baseline;
background: transparent;
display: inline;
}

.form-submit { 
    background-image: url(http://etraining-dev.esc.rl.ac.uk/Apply.jpg);
    background-position:  0px 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 48px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 0px;

}
.form-submit:hover{ 
//      background-position:  0px -52px;
}

.form-submit:active{
      background-position:  0px -104px;
}

A:link {text-decoration: none}
A:visited {text-decoration: none}
A:active {text-decoration: none}
A:hover {font-size:32; font-weight:bold; color: red;}

.font-family
{
//font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter", "Lucida Console", Monaco, "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", monospace;
font-family: 'Droid Sans',arial,serif;
line-height: 1.5em;
color:#333
}
.advanced
{
display:inline;
}

</style>
</head>


<body>
<form action = "advanced_search_dev" method= "get" id = "views-exposed-form-advanced-search-dev-page-11" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div><div class = views-exposed-form1">
<div class = "views-widget_before">
<div class = "font-family">
<b> Keyword </b> <br>
<input title="Enter the terms you wish to search for." type="text" id="edit-keys" name="keys" value="" size="15" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
</div>
</div>
 <div class = "views-widget_before" style = "display:inline">
<input type="submit" id="edit-submit-advanced-search-dev" name="" value=" " class="form-submit">
</div>
</form> 
<div class = "font-family">

<div id="more"><a href = "#" style = "font-size:18px; ">More Option</a></div>

<div id="less"><a href = "#"><b>Less Option</b></a></div>
</div>
<div class = "advanced">
<div id="panel">
<form action="advanced_search_dev" method="get" id="views-exposed-form-advanced-search-dev-page-1" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<div class = "font-family">
<div class="views-exposed-form">
<fieldset>
<legend><b>Search for Training</b></legend>  
<div class = "views-widget">
<div class = "type">
<b>Type</b><br>
<select id="edit-type" name="type" class="form-select">
<option value="All" selected="selected">- Any -</option>
<option value="event">Events</option>
<option value="online_training">Materials</option>
<option value="training_resources">Resources</option>
<option value="webinar">Webinars</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class = "views-widget">
<div class = "country">
<b>Country</b><br>
<select id="edit-tid" name="tid" class="form-select">
<option value="All" selected="selected">- Any -</option>
<option value="10909">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="10910">Albania</option>
<option value="10911">Algeria</option>
<option value="10912">American Samoa</option>
<option value="10913">Andorra</option>
<option value="10914">Angola</option>
<option value="10915">Anguilla</option>
<option value="10916">Antarctica</option>
<option value="10917">Antigua</option>
<option value="10918">Argentina</option>
<option value="10919">Armenia</option>
<option value="10920">Aruba</option>
<option value="10921">Australia</option>
<option value="10922">Austria</option>
<option value="10923">Azerbaijan</option>
<option value="10924">Bahamas</option>
<option value="10925">Bahrain</option>
<option value="10926">Bangladesh</option>
<option value="10927">Barbados</option>
<option value="10928">Belarus</option>
<option value="10929">Belgium</option>
<option value="10930">Belize</option>
<option value="10931">Benin</option>
<option value="10932">Bermuda</option>
<option value="10933">Bhutan</option>
<option value="10934">Bolivia</option>
<option value="10935">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
<option value="10936">Botswana</option>
<option value="10937">Brazil</option>
<option value="10938">British Virgin Islands</option>
<option value="10939">Brunei</option>
<option value="10940">Bulgaria</option>
<option value="10941">Burkina Faso</option>
<option value="10942">Burma</option>
<option value="10943">Burundi</option>
<option value="10944">Cambodia</option>
<option value="10945">Cameroon</option>
<option value="10946">Canada</option>
<option value="10947">Cape Verde</option>
<option value="10948">Central African Republic</option>
<option value="10949">Chad</option>
<option value="10950">Chile</option>
<option value="10951">China</option>
<option value="10952">Colombia</option>
<option value="10953">Comoros</option>
<option value="10954">Congo</option>
<option value="10955">Congo (Zaire)</option>
<option value="10956">Cook Islands</option>
<option value="10957">Costa Rica</option>
<option value="10958">Cote d'Ivoire (Ivory Coast)</option>
<option value="10959">Croatia</option>
<option value="10960">Cuba</option>
<option value="10961">Cyprus</option>
<option value="10962">Czech Republic</option>
<option value="10963">Denmark</option>
<option value="10964">Djibouti</option>
<option value="10965">Dominica</option>
<option value="10966">Dominican Republic</option>
<option value="10967">Ecuador</option>
<option value="10968">Egypt</option>
<option value="10969">El Salvador</option>
<option value="10970">Equatorial Guinea</option>
<option value="10971">Eritrea</option>
<option value="10972">Estonia</option>
<option value="10973">Ethiopia</option>
<option value="10974">Falkland Islands</option>
<option value="10975">Federated States of Micronesia</option>
<option value="10976">Fiji</option>
<option value="10977">Finland</option>
<option value="10978">France</option>
<option value="10979">French Guiana</option>
<option value="10980">French Polynesia</option>
<option value="10981">Gabon</option>
<option value="10982">Gaza Strip and West Bank</option>
<option value="10983">Georgia</option>
<option value="10984">Germany</option>
<option value="10985">Ghana</option>
<option value="10986">Gibraltar</option>
<option value="10987">Greece</option>
<option value="10988">Greenland</option>
<option value="10989">Grenada</option>
<option value="10990">Guadeloupe</option>
<option value="10991">Guam</option>
<option value="10992">Guatemala</option>
<option value="10993">Guinea</option>
<option value="10994">Guinea-Bissau</option>
<option value="10995">Guyana</option>
<option value="10996">Haiti</option>
<option value="10997">Honduras</option>
<option value="10998">Hong Kong</option>
<option value="10999">Hungary</option>
<option value="11000">Iceland</option>
<option value="11001">India</option>
<option value="11002">Indonesia</option>
<option value="11003">Iran</option>
<option value="11004">Iraq</option>
<option value="11005">Ireland</option>
<option value="11006">Israel</option>
<option value="11007">Italy</option>
<option value="11008">Jamaica</option>
<option value="11009">Japan</option>
<option value="11010">Jordan</option>
<option value="11011">Kazakhstan</option>
<option value="11012">Kenya</option>
<option value="11013">Kiribati</option>
<option value="11014">Kuwait</option>
<option value="11015">Kyrgyzstan</option>
<option value="11016">Laos</option>
<option value="11017">Latvia</option>
<option value="11018">Lebanon</option>
<option value="11019">Lesotho</option>
<option value="11020">Liberia</option>
<option value="11021">Libya</option>
<option value="11022">Liechtenstein</option>
<option value="11023">Lithuania</option>
<option value="11024">Luxembourg</option>
<option value="11025">Macau</option>
<option value="11026">Macedonia</option>
<option value="11027">Madagascar</option>
<option value="11028">Malawi</option>
<option value="11029">Malaysia</option>
<option value="11030">Maldives</option>
<option value="11031">Mali</option>
<option value="11032">Malta</option>
<option value="11033">Marshall Islands</option>
<option value="11034">Martinique</option>
<option value="11035">Mauritania</option>
<option value="11036">Mauritius</option>
<option value="11037">Mayotte</option>
<option value="11038">Mexico</option>
<option value="11039">Moldova</option>
<option value="11040">Monaco</option>
<option value="11041">Mongolia</option>
<option value="11131">Montenegro</option>
<option value="11042">Montserrat</option>
<option value="11043">Morocco</option>
<option value="11044">Mozambique</option>
<option value="11045">Namibia</option>
<option value="11046">Nauru</option>
<option value="11047">Nepal</option>
<option value="11048">Netherlands</option>
<option value="11049">Netherlands Antilles</option>
<option value="11050">New Caledonia</option>
<option value="11051">New Zealand</option>
<option value="11052">Nicaragua</option>
<option value="11053">Niger</option>
<option value="11054">Nigeria</option>
<option value="11055">North Korea</option>
<option value="11056">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
<option value="11057">Norway</option>
<option value="11058">Oman</option>
<option value="11059">Pakistan</option>
<option value="11060">Palau</option>
<option value="11061">Panama</option>
<option value="11062">Papua New Guinea</option>
<option value="11063">Paraguay</option>
<option value="11064">Peru</option>
<option value="11065">Philippines</option>
<option value="11066">Pitcairn Islands</option>
<option value="11067">Poland</option>
<option value="11068">Portugal</option>
<option value="11069">Puerto Rico</option>
<option value="11070">Qatar</option>
<option value="11071">Reunion</option>
<option value="11072">Romania</option>
<option value="11073">Russia</option>
<option value="11074">Rwanda</option>
<option value="11075">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
<option value="11076">Saint Lucia</option>
<option value="11077">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
<option value="11078">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
<option value="11079">Samoa</option>
<option value="11080">San Marino</option>
<option value="11081">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
<option value="11082">Saudi Arabia</option>
<option value="11083">Senegal</option>
<option value="11084">Serbia</option>
<option value="11085">Seychelles</option>
<option value="11086">Sierra Leone</option>
<option value="11087">Singapore</option>
<option value="11088">Slovakia</option>
<option value="11089">Slovenia</option>
<option value="11090">Solomon Islands</option>
<option value="11091">Somalia</option>
<option value="11092">South Africa</option>
<option value="11093">South Korea</option>
<option value="11094">Spain</option>
<option value="11095">Sri Lanka</option>
<option value="11096">Sudan</option>
<option value="11097">Suriname</option>
<option value="11098">Swaziland</option>
<option value="11099">Sweden</option>
<option value="11100">Switzerland</option>
<option value="11101">Syria</option>
<option value="11102">Taiwan</option>
<option value="11103">Tajikistan</option>
<option value="11104">Tanzania</option>
<option value="11105">Thailand</option>
<option value="11106">The Gambia</option>
<option value="11107">The Holy See</option>
<option value="11108">Togo</option>
<option value="11109">Tonga</option>
<option value="11110">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
<option value="11111">Tunisia</option>
<option value="11112">Turkey</option>
<option value="11113">Turkmenistan</option>
<option value="11114">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
<option value="11115">Tuvalu</option>
<option value="11116">Uganda</option>
<option value="11117">Ukraine</option>
<option value="11118">United Arab Emirates</option>
<option value="11119">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="11120">United States of America</option>
<option value="11121">United States Virgin Islands</option>
<option value="11122">Uruguay</option>
<option value="11123">Uzbekistan</option>
<option value="11124">Vanuatu</option>
<option value="11125">Venezuela</option>
<option value="11126">Vietnam</option>
<option value="11127">Western Sahara</option>
<option value="11128">Yemen</option>
<option value="11129">Zambia</option>
<option value="11130">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
</select>
</div>

<div class = "views-widget">
<b>Project</b><br>
<select id="edit-tid-1" name="tid_1" class="form-select">
<option value="All" selected="selected">- Any -</option>
<option value="16110">CERN</option>
<option value="16111">CLARIN</option>
<option value="16112">DARIAH</option>
<option value="16113">EGI-InSPIRE</option>
<option value="16114">EMI</option>
<option value="16128">ENVRI</option>
<option value="16115">EPSRC</option>
<option value="16116">EUDAT</option>
<option value="16129">GridPP</option>
<option value="16117">HMRC</option>
<option value="16118">LSGC</option>
<option value="16119">MeDIA</option>
<option value="16120">NAG</option>
<option value="16121">NSCCS</option>
<option value="16122">PRACE</option>
<option value="16123">Scalalife</option>
<option value="16124">SeIUCCR</option>
<option value="16125">SSI</option>
<option value="16126">STFC</option>
<option value="16127">WeNMR</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class = "views-widget">
<b>Research Community</b><br>
<select id="edit-tid-2" name="tid_2" class="form-select">
<option value="All" selected="selected">- Any -</option>
<option value="16064">Agricultural Sciences</option>
<option value="16065">-Agricultural biotechnology</option>
<option value="16066">-Agriculture, forestry, and fisheries</option>
<option value="16067">-Animal and dairy science</option>
<option value="16068">-Veterinary science</option>
<option value="16069">Engineering and Technology</option>
<option value="16070">-Aerospace engineering</option>
<option value="16071">-Bioengineering and Biomedical engineering</option>
<option value="16072">-Chemical engineering</option>
<option value="16073">-Civil Engineering</option>
<option value="16074">-Electrical, electronic and information engineering</option>
<option value="16075">-Environmental biotechnology</option>
<option value="16076">-Environmental engineering</option>
<option value="16077">-Industrial Biotechnology</option>
<option value="16078">-Materials engineering and science</option>
<option value="16079">-Mechanical engineering</option>
<option value="16080">-Nano-technology</option>
<option value="16081">Humanities</option>
<option value="16082">-Arts</option>
<option value="16083">-History and Archaeology</option>
<option value="16084">-Languages and literature</option>
<option value="16085">-Philosophy, ethics and religion</option>
<option value="16086">Medical and Health Sciences</option>
<option value="16087">-Basic medicine</option>
<option value="16088">-Clinical medicine</option>
<option value="16089">-Health sciences</option>
<option value="16090">-Medical biotechnology</option>
<option value="16091">Natural Sciences</option>
<option value="16092">-Biological sciences</option>
<option value="16093">-Computer sciences</option>
<option value="16094">-Earth sciences</option>
<option value="16095">-Information sciences</option>
<option value="16096">-Mathematics</option>
<option value="16097">-Space Science</option>
<option value="16098">Physical Sciences</option>
<option value="16099">-Chemical sciences</option>
<option value="16100">-Physics</option>
<option value="16101">Social Sciences</option>
<option value="16102">-Economics, finance and business</option>
<option value="16103">-Educational sciences</option>
<option value="16104">-Law</option>
<option value="16105">-Media and communications</option>
<option value="16106">-Political Science</option>
<option value="16107">-Psychology</option>
<option value="16108">-Social and economic geography</option>
<option value="16109">-Sociology</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class = "views-widget">
<b> Keyword </b> <br>
<input title="Enter the terms you wish to search for." type="text" id="edit-keys" name="keys" value="" size="15" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
</div>

 <div class = "views-widget" style = "display:inline">
<input type="submit" id="edit-submit-advanced-search-dev" name="" value=" " class="form-submit">
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help?

Comment: can you show that code?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/97145/how-to-add-jquery-code-to-drupal-site/97146#97146 - may this can help you..

Comment: only first 4 lines are JQuery, then some CSS and rest is all HTML.
I have to again add this block on Front Page.

Comment: remove `Keyword` and `Search for Training Type` blocks from the post... Or leave part of them

Comment: I have attached the output (screenshot). Please check.
I can't remove Keyword and Search for Training. I need them.

Comment: ok, i understand what do you want to do.. but I think you need to create a block with hook_block_info() and hook_block_view() functions and render your html content with it. Then you can place it from Block admin page. But before beginning the coding you should read about Render Arrays in drupal.

Comment: Please see [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Do we really need all of it here?! Couldn't you trim it to the essential parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very broad question and it will be hard to answer it completely.

I suggest that you use a tutorial to learn to [create custom blocks](http://fourkitchens.com/blog/2012/07/18/building-custom-blocks-drupal-7). Make sure you separate CSS and JS into separate files and use the [`attached` property](http://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/adding-css-and-js-cached-block-drupal-7) to add the CSS and JS to the output.

If needed, come back to this site and ask more specific questions.

Comment: I have just figured out that instead of writing this code, I found these two lines which replaced this code.

print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('search_block_form'));

print views_embed_view('advanced_search_dev','page_1', $node->nid);

I have a view called Advanced Search. Now the problem is it display the result on the same page after the select buttons, I want the result to be displayed on next page when I click the Apply button.

Any idea?

Comment: My answer remains more or less the same: Create a custom block. In your hook_block_view implementation, you can call any function you need to generate the output you need. Place the block somewhere on your page.

Comment: I created a custom block in hook_block_view, but nothing happened. As it says that once I put the code in the file, it will turn up in the structure->block but it didn't.

Currently I have a view->Page which has some exposed filters and fields. By writing print views_embed_view('advanced_search_dev','page_1', $node->nid); in the block, I am able to access it on the page I want. But it displays the result down there on the same page. I want result on next page. I assume it is something to do with views setting which I don't know what.

Comment: To explain my doubt clearly.
Please visit http://egitraining.esc.rl.ac.uk/advanced_search
Here I have some select statements and result on it's below. I want result on the next page. I have created this Search using a View.

Comment: That sounds like you didn't really read the tutorial I linked to in my answer. You never print anything in hook_block_view, you return the content. Please read, try, think, read more, try again, and if you don't succeed, ask a new, more specific question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I think I was unable to clear my point. I tried the tutorial which you have given me but when I completed the part "Making the block Selectable" it says that I can see my block in Structure->Block.But I couldn't see.
http://egitraining.esc.rl.ac.uk/images/1.jpg
And then I created a block manually and wrote those print statements which is working for me. I want to add CSS and JS file now.
http://egitraining.esc.rl.ac.uk/images/2.jpg
I tried your 2nd tutorial for that but nothing happened. 
Here is the file, http://egitraining.esc.rl.ac.uk/images/3.jpg
Thanks for your time

Comment: Are you editing block.api.php? That's not going to work. You can only implement a hook in your own module. Never change Drupal core files. What you do in 2.jpg may seem to work now, but it will get you in trouble later on. Don't do it. If you never created a module yourself, follow the [tutorial on Drupal.org](https://drupal.org/node/1074360), which happens to teach how to add a custom block. PS. Not to be rude, but my support stops here. We have already stretched StackExchange's question-and-answer concept way too far.

Comment: Hi marcvangend,
Thanks for your reply. I was not being rude. I am sorry if you feel so. I am just explaining what I did. I appreciate your help and time. I am sorry once again.

Comment: No, you were not rude! You don't have to apologize for anything. The phrase "Not to be rude, but..." means that *I* did not want to be rude to *you*. I wish you good luck with your project. Please do return to this site and ask more questions. The more specific your questions are, the better we can help you.